# High School Physics in Mathematical Terms

Tags: resource-recommendations, education

I am looking for a book which explains high school physics using as much math as possible (math level can be beyond high school). I will not go into explaining why I prefer to read/learn physics that way. I will appreciate recommendations for books or other resources.

Comment: "high school physics" is not a well defined phrase. Different high schools in different countries have different level of physics education. Have a look at here. http://www.motionmountain.net/ or http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/

Comment: @physicopath Well, take any high school you want. My definition doesn't have to be one-to-one with all possible subsets of the material... The bottleneck is obviously on the resources.

Comment: Google cannot evaluate textbooks for you. You have to do that yourself, as you have indicated that you will in response to the suggestion by SR810. What's stopping you from looking at the results of your own searches in the same way? Halliday & Resnick is the #2 recommendation in the first answer on Quora.

Comment: @sammygerbil That's true. But if I don't ask the question I will spend at least a few hours evaluating the hundreds of books for myself. While 1) asking the question here will spare me time and other people having the same question in the future as well. 2) My goal isn't to get better at evaluating books to fit my query after all.

Comment: It's extremely unclear to me what you actually want. It is common for high-school physics to range pretty much all over physics, so saying "but with better maths" sounds pretty synonymous with just "university-level physics" to me. If what you want is a single well-rounded textbook that takes a good introductory look at a wide range of subjects (and if so, which ones?) with a solid grounding in (algebra / calculus / including vector calculus / i.e. *what* level of maths?) then just say so, instead of using a description ("high-school physics") that is essentially devoid of meaning.

Comment: Couple of comments deleted. A reminder: Comments are for improving and clarifying the question. They are not for a) giving answers b) debating the friendliness of other users c) discussing issues not directly pertaining to the question itself. Please use chat if you want to have a freeform discussion, and take it to meta and/or flag if you have an issue with other users' behaviour.

Comment: @ACuriousMind Why did you add your own comment then? It doesn't match your own requirements for a comment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what topics you want to cover. If you're thinking of covering all of what is traditionally covered in a 2-semester University course, then any of the standard textbooks would work. Someone mentioned Resnick, Halliday, and Walker, I prefer Young and Freedman, and I like some of the presentations in Knight. The *Six Ideas that Shaped Physics* series by Thomas Moore is more conversational, and takes a bit more of a unified view of "physics as a model". In addition, there is the three-volume [free and open-source textbook](https://openstax.org/details/books/university-physics-volume-1) put out by Open Stax. Unfortunately, I cannot "recommend" this book, but the price is right.

One thing to note when you are looking at these books; if you want math "beyond high school", you probably are talking about Calculus, so you want to look for books that advertise as being "University" text books, rather than "College" textbooks, which are traditionally only based on Algebra.

I am also assuming you are talking about introductory textbooks; otherwise I could recommend things like Jackson for electromagnetism, Griffiths for Quantum Mechanics, and Taylor (or Fowles and Cassiday) for Analytical Mechanics. Or, the *creme de la creme* of physics textbooks, the Landau and Lifshitz series.

Finally, every single person who is qualified to answer this question will have at least 5 opinions about it. I invite edits and suggestions for other textbooks; we all have our favorites, but none of them are perfect!

Comment: -1 This answer does not conform with the policy on resource recommendations, which is summarised above.

Comment: So the Op asks for recommendations which go beyond high school mathematics, I response with recommendations that include college-level mathematics, and that's somehow outside the policy? OP might have been unclear, but I think my answer is good-faith, and in line with "the policy" as outlined above, no? Or did the policy you refer to get deleted?

Comment: Have you read the instructions above? It says "detail the style, content and pre-requisites of the book." The aim is to explain why the book is suitable to the OP's needs, not simply mention titles of those you like.